# Font Awesome doesn't work with CSS rotation

Tags: html, css, rotation, font-awesome, transformation

I am trying to rotate the icons on hover over. It doesn't seem to be working for me. The transition effect works fine. I wonder if I am using wrong tags for applying the rotation. Here is the code:

```css
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css';
@import 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css';
.list-icon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
}
.aticon i {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5e8cfa;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 60px;
}
.icon-wrapper:hover i {
  background: #fff;
  color: #5e8cfa;
  border: 1px solid #5e8cfa;
  transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
  display: inline-block;
}
.aticon:hover .fa {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
}
.list-icon-wrapper .icon-wrapper p {
  padding: 0 5px;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="list-icon-wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="icon-wrapper">
      <span class="aticon">
                    <i class="fa fa-magnet"></i>
                </span>
      <p>Magnet</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="icon-wrapper">
      <span class="aticon">
                   <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                </span>
      <p>Clock</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: They look to be rotating to me: https://jsfiddle.net/g3rh87nb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FontAwesome actually renders the icon on the `:before` pseudo-element rather than as a background image. I think all you need to do is target that rather than the `.fa` element. This should get you started.

```css
.icon-wrapper:hover .fa::before {
    background: #fff;
    color: #5e8cfa;
    border: 1px solid #5e8cfa;
    transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
        -moz-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;
      display: inline-block;
}


.aticon:hover .fa::before {
    transform-origin: center;
      -ms-transform-origin: center;
      -webkit-transform-origin: center;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);

}
```

Comment: It worked great! Thank you! I also had to apply color and border styles to the i selector rather than the .fa::before. Now it looks great! Thank you!